# Is there anyway to make any other keyboard quick prediction insert like Swift Key?

Tags: gboard

I love swiftkey I use it as my main keyboard typing layout.

It autocorrects words like rhe->the automatically when you hit space.
It is called quick prediction insert.

Is there any way to get this effect in GBoard or effectively any other keyboard? iOS works this way.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use Swiftkey if it does what you want?

Comment: 2 words budget phones

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Gboard settings > Text Correction
2. In the Correction section, enable Auto-Correction. Word like `rhe` will automatically be corrected to `the` when you press the Space bar.

[image: IMG:]

When using Gboard version 10.0.02.338070508, an indication of the auto-correction  for the word `rhe` by **`the`** being bolded among the suggested words. When it is not in bold, it won't be auto-corrected.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: You have not used swift key if you think these are equivalent.  Alternatively there is something wrong with my play store or installation.

Comment: You wrote "It autocorrects words like rhe->the automatically when you hit space". And my answer shows that Gboard can accomplish it. So what is the complain? "Alternatively there is something wrong with my play store or installation", what has that have to do with your question?

Comment: "Is there any way to get this effect in GBoard or effectively any other keyboard?". I wrote an answer showing that Gboard can also auto-correct when pressing the space bar. What I don't understand is your complaint about what the feature is called in swiftkey, and not in gboard? Is your question about how the feature is named in other apps? Does your gboard not auto correct words after following the steps mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I have determined what is wrong there is a 2nd option under the settings. I have added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is practically useless because you can always tap the word on the suggestion strip easily.

No (after considering possible scenarios) it is not possible in gboard because even if you somehow get it to write words on tapping spacebar (with Automate app.. i can suggest method for that if you want.. but it will be pointless in my opinion) then you won't get it to be "intelligent" (I mean when you don't want the suggest word and just willing to hit a simple space)

Comment: iOS works this way also so not useless.  I rarely have a word that is not in the default dictionary.  Automate app sounds interesting.

Comment: If you post the automate app I'll post the bounty.

Comment: This solution is going to be complex and will consume additional battery (less tho) But if you want it I'll post it. So what the automate app will do is check the keystrokes. If first key pressed is space then check the second key, if that too is space then insert the middle word from the suggestion strip(explained later) but if the second key is not spacebar then don't do anything. We will need an "interact with UI" block to select the middle word. Yeah.. that's it.. I'll say again it's gonna consume battery and is useless cause you can tap the word on the suggestion strip.

Comment: Ping me if you agree with the suggestion above =)

Comment: I don't agree... I just use SwiftKey then.

Comment: Yeah, that's what you should do.. =)